# Task speed difference between main function and ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

So, I have an executor service that creates 12 threads with 250ms of sleep in between each, this amount of time is usually sufficient for most of my threads to complete, however I have one thread created that is especially process intensive and usually takes about 7-10 seconds to parse.

If I let that run in my main thread, it completes without error, however if I feed it into my executor service, it doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);
...
Thread.sleep(250);
OPA.OpaHandler OpaSH = new OPA.OpaHandler();
    threadPool.submit(new ThreadHandler(OpaSH, 7));
Thread.sleep(250);
...

ThreadHandler.java
....
 public void run(){
    double startTime;
    double endTime;
        switch(this.threadNum){
....
          case 7:{
               startTime = System.nanoTime();
               OpaSH.run();
               endTime = System.nanoTime();
               endTime = endTime - startTime;
               System.out.println("Thread 7 (OPA) took:" + (endTime/1000000000) + " seconds. to run");
               break;
           }
```

The only notable part of OpaSH.run();

```
 supply = new double[9];
        // Create an XML reader
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);

        //Parse the Xml.
        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Stuff[1]/text()");

        result = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        supply[0] = Double.parseDouble(result);

        expr = xpath.compile("//Stuff[2]/text()");

        result = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        supply[1] = Double.parseDouble(result);

        ....
```

There is a total of 12 threads that run, the time to complete each is between 0.07s and 0.8s to compute.  There are two that take significantly longer (about 9s and OPA which can be anywhere from 1s to 55s)

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Any chance you are submitting more than 12 jobs and it is waiting for a pool thread?

Comment: Nope, they all submit with the numbers 1-12 (and at present I'm only submitting 10 to the pool).

Comment: "completes without error" -> what error?

Comment: You are submitting a `ThreadHandler` which is in turn calling `OpaSH.run()`.  Can you show us `ThreadHandler.run()`?  Does the OPA  `println` show the time difference?

Comment: How many CPUs do you have? Is the task CPU bound? If it is and you have only one core, each task can take 12x or more longer. If the process isn't completing, it sounds like you are getting a deadlock. I would take a thread dump with `jstack` to see what the threads are doing.

Comment: In my case I'm actually calling a sleep,250 after each thread gets submitted.  This is also the 7th thread submitted on a hyperthreading quad core.

Comment: As jtalhorn asked, what error? Also it might be better if you can clarify in the question if the problem is the error or the fact that this thread takes longer to run.

Comment: do you just want the jobs to run outside of the main thread one by one? And that's why you sleep 250ms after you submit a job?

Comment: -1 for failing to explain the error that occurs when OPA is run in an Executor vs the main thread.  I will remove the downvote when the post is updated to include this information.

Comment: Also, is it possibly you're using the same OpaSH instance for all your handlers, and that it's "run()" method is doing something that's not threadsafe?  Based on your description, you don't have more than 1 running at a time until you submit this long running one, which means that multiple threads are using OpaSH at the same time.

Comment: @JimGarrison There is no error, it simply times out and hangs.

Comment: @Matt I'm not 100% sure if it's threadsafe or not.  I use httpclient to fetch (via httpget) an xml file and then parse important data from that data using Xpath.

Comment: Allow me to clarify: it's not a http hang, the http status is 200, the program simply does not continue and I get errors for missing (NPE) when I output after a certain amount of time waiting (30s) after all threads are submitted.   When I run OpaSH.run() from main, it takes basically 1-3 seconds, based on when the httpget is fully finished.

Comment: In that case, the problem is in OpaSH.  You're going to have to run this in an IDE with a debugger (Eclipse, Netbeans, etc) and figure out where it's hung.  Alternatively, take a thread dump while it's in the hung state to see which line in OpaSH is the problem.

Comment: you aren't perhaps using a shared instance of HttpClient (the default setup is _not_ thread safe).

Comment: Why don't you put a few `System.out.println`s in the `run()` method to see exactly which step hangs? And if it is always the same step. It might be helpful.